# Why can't I use `g = torch.Generator(); g.manual_seed(0); torch.randint(-100, 100, [3, 2])` to reproduce the work?

Tags: python, random, pytorch

Here is the question, the following code is not reproducible, which means that every time the result changes:
`import torch`

`g = torch.Generator()`

`g.manual_seed(0)`

`torch.randint(-100, 100, [3, 2])`

But directly use `torch.manual_seed(0)` works.

So does everybody know why `g=torcg.Generator()` can not work?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your generator `g` in your `torch.randint` call.

`torch.randint` has an optional `generator` argument.

E.g.

```
torch.randint(-100, 100, [3, 2], generator=g)
```

See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randint.html